# How to compare value from sum() with mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to compare the value from `sum()` which I declared as `tt_buy`. But when I compare at the end. I got an error :

`Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'tt_buy' in 'where clause'`

Here is my code :

```
select *,sum(b.buy) tt_buy from huay_today_bet b
    inner join huay_today t on t.hid=b.hid
    inner join settings_price_level l on l.rid=t.sid
    where b.hid=? and b.pmode=? and b.num=? and l.lv_bet<tt_buy
```

I know there anything wrong with my comparison. But I don't know what to search with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query tt_buy was used as alias. Here I use subquery to avoid error. In MySQL everything is possible so GROUP BY isn't used. But need to use GROUP BY for proper writting query. Different alias name uses if multiple columns with same name.

```
-- MySQL 
SELECT t.*
FROM (select *,sum(b.buy) tt_buy from huay_today_bet b
    inner join huay_today t on t.hid=b.hid
    inner join settings_price_level l on l.rid=t.sid
    where b.hid=? and b.pmode=? and b.num=? ) t
WHERE t.lv_bet<t.tt_buy
```

Comment: Hi @Wilf please check the above query and let me know if any query regard this. It's just a sample code. But if you provide sample data then I'll try to write perfect query.

Comment: I got `#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'`.

Comment: Hi @Wilf please alias all table id column or common name column inside subquery please alias as different name for avoiding this type of error. Example t.hid as htodayid, b.hid as betid

Comment: Ok, I'll give a try.

Comment: I changed all related `id` in this code. It works but another problem come up. Same column name needs error as duplicated as well. I don't want to change all name. Is there any solution?

Comment: Do you need all columns for this 3 tables. If no need all columns please select necessary columns of this 3 tables and if any common name exists try to replace different name as alias instead of *.

Comment: Got it now. Thank you for the clue. I changed `(select *` to `(select t.lv_bet` and it works as I want.